# Differentiate between drop and sort in jQuery UI sortable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am using jquery UI draggable and sortable for drag and drop functionality. I am running a function when user drag a field into the droppable area.
Here's my code

```
let initDrag = () => {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.droppable',
        cursor: "crosshair",
        helper: "clone",
        opacity: 0.35,
        snap: true,
        refreshPositions: true
    })
}
let initSortable = () => {
    $( ".droppable" ).sortable({
        update: afterDrop
    });
}
let afterDrop = (event, ui) => {
    let fieldID = ui.item.attr("data-id");
    getFieldData(fieldID).then(fieldData => {
        fieldData[0].field.field_id = Date.now();
        formBuildingJSON.form_fields.push(fieldData[0]);
        console.log(formBuildingJSON);
    })
}
```

I want to only run this `afterDrop()` function when user drag the field in dropable area. But this function also fires whenever user sorts the element. So how can I detect whether the field has been dragged in or sorted. I am creating an array that store the id of all the dragged elements. Now when user sorts the elements I want this array to be reordered. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or pen of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correcly, you should add a `stop: afterDrop` on your `.draggable()`. The `afterDrop` method is called only when a new item is added. You can reorder the items later, but it will not fire again.

Check the following snippet.

```js
let afterDrop = (event, ui) => {
  console.log('afterDrop')
}

$(function () {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
  });
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    stop: afterDrop
  });
  $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <style>
  ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  li {
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 150px;
  }
 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <ul>
  <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
 </ul>

 <ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
 </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great this works! But another thing stopped working. Inside `afterDrop()` I am trying to get the `data-id` of dropped element. But now using `ui.item.attr("data-id")` but now ui object don't have it